# loading data to my mainform

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

studentrecords table.,.,contains IDNumber,LastName,Course,Firstname

i will login through my system using IDNumber and once i go to the mainform iwant to display LASTname and course to the 2 textboxes in the mainform using the IDNumber as their Primary Key.,.My code errors

Dim con As New OleDbConnection
     Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

```
  Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

  Dim dt As New DataTable

  Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty

  'get connection string declared in the Module1.vb and assing it to conn variable

  con = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)

  con.Open()

  cmd.Connection = con

  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
  sSQL = "SELECT  LastName FROM studentsrecords where IDNumber like '%" & studentslogin.[txtIDNumber].Text & "%' order by ID desc"

  cmd.CommandText = sSQL

  da.SelectCommand = cmd

  da.Fill(dt)

  'evalutionrate.[lbllogin].Text = studentslogin.[txtIDNumber].Text

  evalutionrate.[lbllogin].Text = sSQL

  evalutionrate.Show()
```

Answer (score -1):

here: just make a new label "label= lbllogin and "hide" it in welcome or mainform as it will be the key to read your database.

```
Private Sub Mainform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
    lbllogin.Text = Login.studentslogin.Text
    Dim sqlquery As String = "select * from studentsrecords where IDNumber =@ID"
    Dim sqlcommad As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlread As OleDbDataReader
    sqlcommad.CommandText = sqlquery
    sqlcommad.Connection = conn
    sqlcommad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lbllogin.Text)
    sqlcommad.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlread = sqlcommad.ExecuteReader
    Try
        If (sqlread.Read()) Then
            textbox1.Text = sqlread("LASTname ")      
            textbox2.Text = sqlread("course ")

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Don't Forget to vote if this answer is useful.

Comment: it only load IDNumber